# Localizations of $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A=\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$. Prove that for each multiplicative subset $\Sigma$ of $A$ there is an integer $n$ such that $\Sigma^{-1}A=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Any thoughts, observations? Tried anything?

Comment: No, i didn´t know how to start.

Answer (score 4):

Ok. First of all some facts about fractions:

Let $R$ be a commutative with identity. A subset $S$ of $R$ is called saturated if for any $a,b \in R$, $ab \in S \longleftrightarrow a,b \in S$. Now if $S$ is a multiplicative closed subset of $R$ the intersection of all saturated subsets of $R$ containing $S$ is denoted by $\bar{S}$ (called the saturation of $S$). The importance of this notion is the following two theorems:

**Theorem 1.** A subset $S$ of $R$ is saturated if anf only if $R\backslash S$ is a union of prime ideals.

**Theorem 2.** For any multiplicative closed subset $S$ of $R$ we have $S^{-1}R \cong {\bar{S}}^{-1}R$.

This means that when working with isomorphisms you can always assume that $S$ is saturated (by Theorem 2) and saturated subsets are more well formed (by Theorem 1). On the other hand the following is also useful:

**Theorem 3.** Suppose $R_1, R_2$ are rings and let $S$ be a saturated subset of $R_1\times R_2$. Then there are saturated subsets $S_1$ in $R_1$ and $S_2$ in $R_2$ such that $S = S_1\times S_2$. (The converse is also clear)

**Theorem 4.**  Suppose $R_1, R_2$ are rings and let $S_1$ be a multiplicative subset of $R_1$ and $S_2$ be a multiplicative subset of  $R_2$ then $(S_1\times S_2)^{-1}(R_1\times R_2) \cong {S_1}^{-1}R_1\times {S_2}^{-1}R_2$.

Now lets return to your problem. Suppose $ p_1^{\alpha_1}\times\cdots\times p_k^{\alpha_k}$ is a factorization of $m$ into distinct primes. Then $A=\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \cong \Bbb{Z}_m \cong \Bbb{Z}_{p_1^{\alpha_1}}\times\cdots\times\Bbb{Z}_{p_k^{\alpha_k}}$. Now aplly Theorems $3,4,1,2$.

Feel free to ask for more explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much, I´ll think about that solution and I´ll try to do the exercise and if I block, I´ll ask you.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: what can you say about the image of a generator of $A$ under the natural map $A \to \Sigma^{-1}A$?

**Edit:** Hint 2: Can you do the case when $n = p^k$ is a prime power? For the general case, consider the Chinese Remainder Theorem.