# Localizations of $ \mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{Z}_{p^k} $ be a multiplicative subset, where $p$ is a prime number, $k$ an integer.

Is it true that $$S^{-1} \mathbb{Z}_{p^k} \cong \mathbb{Z} /n\mathbb{Z} $$ for some integer $n$ ? Why ?

Comment: Are you aware that you use th $n$ to define the muliplicative subset? Do you want this for any mult. subset?

Comment: @MohamedHashi: I've edited, $k$ and $n$ can be different

Comment: @user26857: do you know an answer or where can I find it ?

Comment: @WLOG: For the statement with any $n$, see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/630813/115654)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

The ring $\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$ is local with unique maximal ideal $(p)$.

If $S\cap (p) = \emptyset$, you are inverting units and hence $$S^{-1} \mathbb{Z}_{p^k}\cong \mathbb{Z}_{p^k}=\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}.$$

If $S\cap (p) \neq \emptyset$, then $ap\in S$ for some $a \in \mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$.
But then you get 
$$\frac{1}{1}=\frac{a^{k-1}p^{k-1}}{a^{k-1}p^{k-1}}=\frac{0}{p}=\frac{0}{1}.$$
So you get $$S^{-1} \mathbb{Z}_{p^k}\cong 0=\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}.$$

Comment: But we don't know if $p \in S $. If $p \not\in S$ we can't write $$\frac{1}{p} \in S^{-1} \mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$$

Comment: I have edited it. I don't use this anymore. But you should understand that $\frac{a}{ap}$ plays the role of $\frac{1}{p}$ since we have $\frac{a}{ap}p=1$